# Array is set to data from API request when using push() in Javascript before the API request is declared

Tags: javascript, debugging, asynchronous, fetch-api

How come the first console.log(characters) is returning the data from the API request before the API request is declared when using the push method?

If instead of pushing the data to characters it's just set to the data as in the code that is commented out only the second console.log() returns the data as expected.

In both examples console.log("First console log") always executes first also as expected.
So when using the push() method, console.log("First console log") executes first but the first console.log(characters) still logs the array that is declared before the console.log("First console log") with the data from the fetch().

Using VScode and chrome DevTools.

```
let characters = []
console.log("First console log")
console.log(characters)

fetch("https://hp-api.onrender.com/api/characters")
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
    characters.push(data)
    // characters = data
    console.log(characters)
    console.log("Second console log")
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the output of `console.log()` is a live reference to the array. If the array changes after it was logged, the change will still be observable on the reference.

If you print it as JSON (i.e. `console.log(JSON.stringify(characters))`), you will get `"[]".

And when you set `characters` to a new array, the reference in the console still points to the old, unchanged array.